# C# - Start multiple threads childs of the same "never-closing" father process

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, tensorflow

I need to open a CMD window and run a process that starts an environment (command `activate tensorflow`). Then, when needed, I launch another command that can be considered a thread, with a sequence of other commands, into the same window.

Practically, the father process is always up for allowing me to launch threads inside it. The output of these threads need to be returned and red from the C# program.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Can't get started, other specific issue? Or no idea at all? If you want your question answered don't treat SO like a coding service, show your effort.

Comment: Commands are processes, not threads. They can't be considered threads. Besides, why use threads at all when .NET has tasks, PLINQ, Parallel.Foreach etc? What are you trying to do? What you describe could be written with a simple `var results=(from item in lotsOfItems.AsParallel() select Stuff(item)).ToList();`

Comment: In other words, you don't need parent and child threads or forking and joining. There are other, higher level and much more lightweight constructs available

Comment: _I launch another command that can be considered a thread_ false: you start a new Process, which is something very different from a thread ; first, the new process will have it's own memory space that you cannot access from the main process.
Also, start from [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting a `Process`, you may be interested in redirecting the [input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx), [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) and [error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx) streams of it back to caller. So you can react to I/O operations for your process, and call other functions respectively.

Some samples can be found [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput), also, please, read the official docs I've linked already:

- [`RedirectStandardInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx)
- [`RedirectStandardOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)
- [`RedirectStandardError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx)

Comment: It seems legit ;-) can you share a sample code for doing this in a "three" of processes? Thanks

Comment: @MarcoRaoul If you read the linked articles, you'll find the examples

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know ;-)